# How to asynchronous load image from a web-server in UICollectionView using NSCache

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4, grand-central-dispatch

I have some issues when loading images from a web-server in UICollectionView using NScache.

The problem:

The images are not proper displayed:

1. sometimes  they  are not showned in the corresponding cell

or

2. the image is changing  on scroll

Situation:

1. I have 3 arrays whitch are properly loaded from the web-server in function viewDidLoad(). These arrays are: vPrice, vTitle and vImages_api
2. my custom class for cell have:

   - label for price: cell.lblPrice
   - label for title: cell.lblTitle
   - image: cell.imgPicture

I belive that the problem is in function  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell

It could be related either to the way I use NSCache or to the way I use and when I use DispatchQueue.

The code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionViewPRODUSE.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! clsCustomCell

    cell.lblPrice.text = vPrice[indexPath.item]
    cell.lblTitle.text = vTitle[indexPath.item]

    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        //background thread
        let ImageString = self.vImages_api[indexPath.item]
        let imageUrl = URL(string: ImageString)
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl!)

        // main thread to update the UI
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let key1 = self.vImages_api[indexPath.item] as AnyObject
            //if i saved allready my image in cache, then i will load my image from cache
            if let imageFromCache = self.objCache.object(forKey: key1){
                cell.imgPicture.image = imageFromCache as! UIImage
            }
            else{//if my image is not in cache  ......
                        if imageData != nil {
                            let myPicture = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
                            cell.imgPicture.image = myPicture                 

                            //save my image in cache
                            self.objCache.setObject(myPicture!, forKey: ImageString as AnyObject)
                        }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

**Edited code - version II:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionViewPRODUSE.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! clsCustomCell

    cell.lblPret.text = vPrice[indexPath.item]
    cell.lblTitlu.text = vTitle[indexPath.item]

    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    let key1 = self.vImages_api[indexPath.item] as AnyObject

    if let imageFromCache = self.objCache.object(forKey: key1){
        cell.imgPicture.image = imageFromCache as! UIImage
    }else{
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let ImageString = self.vImages_api[indexPath.item]
            let imageUrl = URL(string: ImageString)
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
            let  myPicture = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
            self.objCache.setObject(poza!, forKey: ImageString as AnyObject)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if imageData != nil {
                        cell.imgPicture.image = myPicture
                    }
                }
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

**Edited code - version III**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.collectionViewPRODUSE.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "celula_custom", for: indexPath) as! clsCustomCell
    cell.lblPret.text = vPrice[indexPath.item]
    cell.lblTitlu.text = vTitle[indexPath.item]

  NKPlaceholderImage(image: UIImage(named: "loading"), imageView: cell.imgPicture, imgUrl:  self.vImages_api[indexPath.item]
    ) { (image11) in
        cell.imgPicture.image = image11
    }
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    return cell
}
```

Comment: "I have 3 arrays": Bad design. Theses 3 items needs to be synced, so use one single array of dictionaries or custom struct, where an object can holds a price value, a title value and imageLink one. `let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl!)` Don't. That's blocking the thread, even if it's in background. You should check BEFORE hand if you have the image in the cache. Your code is unclear because of the two thins you are doing? Is that really your code? Or two attempts?

Comment: As you suggested,  I have checked if the image is stored in Cache before using it in  DispatchQueue.  Now, after editing the code, in version II there is a new situation: sometimes the images are showed correctly in the corresponding cell and are not changing anymore on scroll. But sometimes, on refresh, the images are still displayed in the wrong cell and some of the corresponding description are missing.

Comment: You should do `cell.imgPicture = nil` (or replace it with a placeholder), just before you call the `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`. because cells are reused, to between the start of the download and its end, the image might have an older one. Reuse is an important concept of `UITableView`/`UICollectionView`. If it solves your issues, now that mosts mistakes are cleared (event if `NSData(contentsOf:)` still seems a method to not use and I'd prefer `URLSession` because of errors returns), I'd suggest you use `SDWebImage` or assimilated that do that and much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one it's Working code **(Swift 4)**.

```
func NKPlaceholderImage(image:UIImage?, imageView:UIImageView?,imgUrl:String,compate:@escaping (UIImage?) -> Void){

    if image != nil && imageView != nil {
        imageView!.image = image!
    }

    var urlcatch = imgUrl.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "#")
    let documentpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    urlcatch = documentpath + "/" + "\(urlcatch)"

    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:urlcatch)
    if image != nil && imageView != nil
    {
        imageView!.image = image!
        compate(image)

    }else{

        if let url = URL(string: imgUrl){

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                () -> Void in
                let imgdata = NSData(contentsOf: url)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    () -> Void in
                    imgdata?.write(toFile: urlcatch, atomically: true)
                    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:urlcatch)
                    compate(image)
                    if image != nil  {
                        if imageView != nil  {
                            imageView!.image = image!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Use Like this :**

```
// Here imgPicture = your imageView and UIImage(named: "placeholder") is Display image brfore download actual image.  
imgPicture.image = nil 
NKPlaceholderImage(image: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), imageView: imgPicture, imgUrl: "Put Here your server image Url Sting") { (image) in }
```

Comment: Don't use `NSStuff` when Swift version without the `NS` are available => `NSURL` => `URL`, that will also avoid the `as URL` after.

Comment: @Larme Now check it.

Comment: @Eventful If this solution is worked for you then don't forgot to accept & give upvote it .. happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But I have 2 problems: 1) first time if I scroll down fast while the images are still loading, it is noticeable that in some of the cells the displayed image is changing until all the pictures are loaded. After all photos are loaded, everything is normal and I can scroll up/down and works perfectly.  2) It is correct that  UIImage(named: "placeholder") -> in my case UIImage(named: "loading") it's a generic picture showed before the actual picture is loaded? If so, I used an animated gif (loading gif like a spining wheel) but when loading it is not showed. Any idea why?

Comment: @Eventful Check Updated Answer Set imgPicture.image = nil Just Before Load the Image

Comment: Thanks for answering. One final issue: on scrolling up/down the overall impression is that the images make a small pause in scrolling and then a quick jump to the normal position. Thanks.