# Load Images from URL Xcode 9 in slideshow iOS APP

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

Hi everyone I want to know how to load images from URL even if I added 1,2,3,etc in an app for iOS

The point of this exercise is to change images remotely and show them in the app in real time

Actually I can show images from the iOS device and this is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

var timer: Timer!
var counter = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMAGE_TO_SHOW1")
    counter+=1;
    timer=Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(animate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
@objc func animate(){
    print("Animate Method")

    UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
                      animations: {
                        UIView .setAnimationRepeatCount(5)
                        if(self.counter<6){
                            let name = "IMAGE_TO_SHOW\(self.counter)"
                            self.ImageView.image=UIImage(named: name)
                            self.counter+=1;
                            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                        };if(self.counter==6){
                            self.counter=1

                        }

    }, completion: {finished in


    })
}


}
```

But I can only show 5 images and I need to show n number of images if I want 1 or 2 or 3 or n

example:

If I want 4 images then show

```
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW1
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW2
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW3
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW4
```

And if I want 3 images then show

```
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW1
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW2
https://www.images.com/IMAGE_TO_SHOW3
```

******EDIT******
I’m going to explain what I need

I have 2 stores (my own clothin stores)
I have 4 ipads ( 2 for each store)
I want to show a discount slideshow in each iPad 
I have a server where i can publish images with direct URL (www.domain.com/image1.jpg)
I want to change the slideshow images remotely by uploading images in my server
Sometimes I have 2 discounts and sometimes I have 5 discounts

Actually I have to update the app in order to show new images but i want to do it only by uploading the images into the server
How can I show the slideshow updated images only by changing images on my server?

******EDIT******

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Create simple `api` service to call and return `images array` as `json`. Then you can call api after certain time. Or you can make count infinite and if no data from `url` you can stop loop to fetch more image trying (i don't know this one is best method).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are resetting the counter in animation completion handler as:

```
if(self.counter==6){
     self.counter=1
}
```

Instead of 6 add dynamic count as per your array (if you are saving the image urls in array).

```
if(self.counter==YOUR_IMAGE_URLS_ARRAY_COUNT){
     self.counter=1
}
```

**~ EDIT ~**

For laoding images dynamically yoiu can use [Kingfisher library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

The library provides method for setting image from url with completion handler. If you want you can either set animation inside completion handler or else you can set image with animation.

method you can use:

```
imageViewBg.kf.setImage(with: , placeholder: , options: , progressBlock: , completionHandler: )
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. But how to use URL images instead of using internal images from app

Comment: your question is quite unclear then, anyways you can load images dynamically using any third party image loader. like [kingfisher library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Comment: I’m sorry I am newbie in iOS, how do I use this library using dynamic count of images

Comment: What I want to do is to upload images to a web page and then the app will take all the images from this web page even if it is 1 , 2 or more images and then show them as slide show (actually shows 5 images as slideshow) thank you

Comment: you requirement is quite unclear. as per the question you want to add images from urls stored in some array. Can you please elaborate the actual requirement? so that to move towards solution easily

Comment: if you are delaing with web view you may create the html with href setting the urls in it, so webview will automatically show the images from urls and then you wont need that library

Comment: I have edited my question please check it, thank you

Comment: Is there a way to get nil using the Kingfisher library?. Just to be clear, if I can get a nil then I can set a big count number and in case the app show a nil URL just reset count to start. in case the answer is affirmative please show me the right way to do it with code, thank you

Comment: as per my understanding, may be you can implement API as @pranavan said, and then load those images only which are updated. to notify to other iPads you can use the push notification to let other devices know the update.

Answer (score 0):

you have started your counter from 1 as "var counter = 1"

after that you are checking it by condition of " if(self.counter<6)"

So in this flow, counter executes condition for 1,2,3,4 and 5. when it gets equal to 6 , condition results false.

What you need to do is,
make your counter equal to 0 and put condition of 
"if counter <= arrayOfImages.count"

Comment: comment if you don't get it. I will explain you using code

Comment: Thank you. Actually my code works fine but it uses the images saved in the app and I need to show the images from the URL and in case the number of images change it should show only the number of images in the URL. It would be nice if you can explain with code.

Comment: @Adan_004 **Here is working code for display image from URL with Placeholder image before Load the Actual image** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746300/10150796