# SD Web Image not caching to disk from Firebase URL

Tags: swift, cache-control, sdwebimage

I am using the following code to set the image in a tableview cell

Image.sd_setImage(with:URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage:"image"), options:[.continueInBackground,.scaleDownLargeImages])

however, after a short period of time(I am assuming when the memory cleared) my images need to be download again. My assumption is that the images are not saving to disk and or my disk is getting purged too often. I have also tried this with kingfisher and am getting the same result. So it seems that it’s a Firebase issue, I have read a bit on cache control headers and I think I have change it so the max age is a year but I’m still getting the same results and I also have no idea how to debug the api call to see if this is the issue

I have tried adding and remove the gobal functions for maxCache and Age etc without any success.

Have i missed something in my code

Comment: **Try this it's working** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746300/10150796

Comment: Are you suggesting that sdweb images has a bug ? Or isn’t working ?

Comment: For this simple thing can't need to use any third-party image cashing library you can do it by using just this one function.

Comment: I was really hoping for something that managed memory for me.

Comment: Please try my Solution it will definitely its work for you.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong but as image are changed in my Firebase URL your solution  will continue to expand  my disk memory forever ? I need a mechanisms for clearing disk occasionally stay every 6 months or so. I would also like to use some of the options sdweb offers.