# Swift4: UIImage from URL

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, uiimage

I have a problem.

I want to get the image from url, and display UIimage in table cell.
`let url` has value but it becomes `nil`

And run this code got error

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Why will the value be `nil`?

```
let url = URL(string: stores![indexPath.row].photos[0].path)

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**stores![indexPath.row].photos[0].path value**

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/NY_0.jpeg`

Comment: Don't use Data(contentsOf: URL) initializer for non local resources URL. You should never download those synchronously.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/NY_0.jpeg doesn't look like a valid url

Comment: The code seem it should work. However you are using local API to fetch the image, `Check if AppTransportSecurity is allowing you to make the request`.

Comment: @kathayatnk I was setting `AppTransportSecurity` but value is nil

Comment: Are you really sure that `stores![indexPath.row].photos[0].path` actually has the exact value `http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/NY_0.jpeg`? That is a perfectly valid URL and that does *not* result in `url` being `nil`. Make sure there is no whitespace in the value.

Comment: @Alex: Check your URL and try to debug. Also if you see that the URL is correct try this link `http://dummyimage.com/227x202.png/cc0000/ffffff` for testing purpose. If this link give you the image then there would be something missing from your local URL

Comment: @kathayatnk Yes. I printed out using `print` and confirmed but the same URL is output. Im test your URL I can display image. My URL miss take thank you

Comment: @Alex Try this one it's working fine https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746300/10150796

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try copying and pasting that URL into a browser and see if the image really does exist?

Also your use of "!" everywhere is asking for a crash.  Only use "!" when you are absolutely sure that what you are unwrapping is not going to be nil.

```
guard let stores = stores else { return cell }
guard indexPath.row < stores.count else { return cell }

if let url = URL( string:stores[indexPath.row].photos.first.path)
{
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
      if let data = try? Data( contentsOf:url)
      {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          cell.imageCell.image = UIImage( data:data)
        }
      }
   }
}

return cell
```

Comment: Yes, I'm checked to get the image from this URL.

Comment: And paste this code i got an error in `guard let stores = stores else { return }`

`guard indexPath.row < stores.count else { return }` part.

Error
`Non-void function should return a value`

Comment: @Alex : The error is because you are not returning the cell from your method, like in your question.

Comment: Have updated my answer with returning cell as pointed out by @kathayatnk