# Core Data prints saved data but not showing up on table viewcontroller

Tags: swift

I would like to show my saved data in core data on a table view controller, the data is saved properly and prints out the details on the console but the data is noot showing up on the tableview cell, kindly please help

```
var charData = [SavedCharacters]()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var name = String()
var house = String()
var ancestry = String()
var getImage = UIImage()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getData()
}
func getData(){
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SavedCharacters")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do{
        let result = try? context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]
        {
            name = data.value(forKey: "name") as! String

            print(data.value(forKey: "name")as! String)
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return charData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! SavedDataTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = charData[indexPath.row].name!
    cell.house = charData[indexPath.row].house!
    cell.ancestry = charData[indexPath.row].ancestry!
    // displaying image in table view cell
    if let imageURL = URL(string: self.charData[indexPath.row].image!) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.charImageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you've forgotten to init charData in getData() method

```
var charData: [CharData]

func getData(){

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SavedCharacters")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    ====> charData = []

    do{
        let result = try? context.fetch(request)
        for data in result as! [CharData]
        {
            name = data.value(forKey: "name") as! String

            print(data.value(forKey: "name")as! String)

            ===> charData.append(data)
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. It worked but now I got a new error for Image as a nil value

Comment: Man, I cannot debug your project for you, but I can suggest - do not ever use explicit optionals (!) - use if let, guard let constructions and early returns

Comment: Oh no worries, I got it, Thank You Very Much though

Comment: @NikhilLadhani I think you need to use this one for load the image in table view https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746300/10150796