# how to get image from api

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to get image from api which is given by backend people and to download the images,i am using "`SDWebImage`" through pods.My requirement is: i will be having a collection of products,in that collection data i have image url.i have to get that product image from that image url and i need to show that image in separate product details `Viewcontroller` But i am getting a run time error like "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"..I am giving my code below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
var imag: String = dict["photo"] as! String
lmpviewcontroller.userimgobj.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:imag), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Avatar-male.png"))
}
```

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: Probably this `URL(string:imag)` is nil. Make sure `imag ` is proper URl string. Check this string by pasting it web browser.

Comment: search once how to pass data from one VC to another VC.

Comment: along with this image ,am sending some data to another vc.it's completely working.

Comment: and in that url ,there is an image .i have checked it as you said.if the image is not there ,at least it has to show the placeholder na..

Comment: @Swathi **Here is Working Code swift 4** with set placeholder image and cashing without using any third-party library  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746300/10150796

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the crashing line but already a potential is shown in the code you posted where you force-unwrap a string value from JSON:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    var imag: String = dict["photo"] as! String
    lmpviewcontroller.userimgobj.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:imag), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Avatar-male.png"))
}
```

The force-unwrapping is with using `!`.

This should be something like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    guard let imageURL: String = dict["photo"] as? String else { return }
    lmpviewcontroller.userimgobj.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Avatar-male.png"))
}
```

By using force-unwrap it means you are 100% sure that this value will always exist. And if id does not then your application will crash.

By checking it optionally you need to check for it existence with either `if let` or `guard let`. In general this is similar to doing:

```
let myOptionalValue: Any?
if myOptionalValue == nil {
    return
} else {
    doSomethingWithMyValue(myOptionalValue!)
}
```

but Swift has nicer syntax as displayed previously.

Comment: @Swathi You should be able to get which is the line that crashes. That would help identifying where the issue is. But from the error this is exactly what has happened. Some tool somewhere expects a value which is nil.

Comment: lmpviewcontroller.userimgobj.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Avatar-male.png"))                                              At this line app getting crashed..

Comment: @Swathi @Swathi This looks like a very old tool. You need to check which of the parameters is optional if any. For each non-optional parameter you need to guard that the value exists. As in: `guard let url = URL(string: imageURL) else { return } `and `UIImage(named: "Avatar-male.png") else { return } `. I would personally expect both are optional but it seems that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if let  imag = dict["photo"]{
      let url = URL(string: imag)
      userimgobj.kf.setImage(with: url)
      }
}
```

Comment: If i use your code,am getting an error like "Ambiguous reference to member 'setImage(with:placeholder:options:progressBlock:completionHandler:)'"

Comment: Did you tried it
'userimgobj.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: nil,options:nil)'

Answer (score 0):

//with sd image

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
            if dict["photo"] != nil{
                    lmpviewcontroller.userimgobj.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:imag)), completed: nil)
                    }else{
                        lmpviewcontroller.userimgobj = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
                    }
    }
```